# Context for "relative paths" seems to change to the calling module if a module is imported

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, relative-path

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
home/
├── module1/
│   ├── index.js
│   └── file.csv
└── module2/
    └── index.js
```

Module 1 `index.js` has code that reads in `file.csv` using a node module called `csvtojson`. `module2/index.js` requires `module1/index.js`.

When I run the code directly from module1 everything works fine and the file is read in successfully. However, when I run the code in module2 I get a "File does not exist." error. Do I need to explicitly make all of my paths absolute?

Comment: Please make this a [mcve] by [edit]ing your question to include the relevant code.

Comment: Please provide at least all your `require()` and `fs.readFile()` lines with used paths.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact same problem using **csvtojson** as well.

Whenever you are using a plain path to a file it is searched relative to the caller script, except when using **require**, which only works for source files and json as far as I know.

But you have the option to use **__dirname**  to get the absolute directory of the specific script it is used in, so you can get the right path like this:

```
const yourPath = __dirname + "/file.csv";
```